# error using L-BFGS-B in scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I get some puzzling result when using the 'L-BFGS-B' method in scipy.optimize.minimize:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy as np

def testFun():
    prec = 1e3

    func0 = lambda x: (float(x[0]*prec)/prec+0.5)**2+(float(x[1]*prec)/prec-0.3)**2
    func1 = lambda x: (float(round(x[0]*prec))/prec+0.5)**2+(float(round(x[1]*prec))/prec-0.3)**2

    result0 = optimize.minimize(func0, np.array([0,0]), method = 'L-BFGS-B', bounds=((-1,1),(-1,1)))
    print result0
    print 'func0 at [0,0]:',func0([0,0]),'; func0 at [-0.5,0.3]:',func0([-0.5,0.3]),'\n'

    result1 = optimize.minimize(func1, np.array([0,0]), method = 'L-BFGS-B', bounds=((-1,1),(-1,1)))
    print result1
    print 'func1 at [0,0]:',func1([0,0]),'; func1 at [-0.5,0.3]:',func1([-0.5,0.3])

def main():
    testFun()
```

func0() and func1() are almost identical quadratic functions with only a precision difference of 0.001 for input values. 'L-BFGS-B' method works well for func0. However, by just adding a round() function in func1(), 'L-BFGS-B' stops to search for optimal values after first step and directly use initial value [0,0] as the optimal point.

This is not just restricted to round(). Replace round() in func1() as int() also results in the same error.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BFGS method is one of those method that relies on not only the function value, but also the gradient and Hessian (think of it as first and second derivative if you wish). In your `func1()`, once you have `round()` in it, the gradient is no longer continuous. BFGS method therefore fails right after the 1st iteration (think of as this: BFGS searched around the starting parameter and found the gradient is not changed, so it stopped). Similarly, I would expect other methods requiring gradient fail as BGFS.

You may be able to get it working by precondition or rescaling X. But better yet, you should try gradient free method such as 'Nelder-Mead' or 'Powell'

Comment: Thanks, Zhu. So basically this is a local minimum rather than global minimum. My concern of using 'Nelder-Mead' or 'Powell' is that they can't take constraints. Eventually, I want to solve a two dimension problem with linear inequality constraints. In your opinion, is Cobyla the best option?

Comment: It's not a matter of it being a local minimum vs. a global minimum.  As soon as you introduce behavior into your constraints or objective which ruins the derivative information, the gradient-based solvers are no longer guaranteed to work, and likely won't.  As Zhu said, use an optimizer that doesn't rely on derivative information if you must use functions like round, int, or abs in your model.

No optimization method that I'm aware of can guarantee a global optimum in finite time.

Comment: 2nded to @Rob Falck. You explained it very well. OP's question is essentially a discrete optimization problem, which I am far from being a expert on. But one more thing for OP, you using 'L-BFGS-B' to set `bounds` not `constrains`, which are different. I have limited experience with Cobyla and can't make that recommendation. But your `f()` are special, it is >=0, which makes `bounds` of [-1,1] easy to implement. I.E. You may be able to use a `g=lambda x: (abs(x)>1)*x*x` and optimize `f(x)*exp(g(x))` instead of `f(x)`.

Comment: Thanks, Rob and Zhu. I see your point, the essential point is that the gradient estimation may not be accurate for func1(). Zhu, my function is not non-negative, so the trick you mentioned may not be directly used. I will figure something out.

Answer (score 6):

`round` and `int` create step functions, which are not differentiable. The l-bfgs-b method is for solving smooth optimization problems.  It uses an approximate gradient (if you don't give it an explicit one), and that will be garbage if the function has steps.