# Different output for the same input using scipy optimize with L-BFGS-B algorithm

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

```
start_values = [0, 0]
bnds = [(0, 100), (0, 100)]

def _equation(self, variables):
    x1 = variables[0]
    x2 = variables[1]
    return abs(-98 + x1*2 + x2) + abs(-99 + x1 + x2)

result = minimize(_equation, tuple(start_values), bounds=bnds).x
```

I have different result for the same input parameter. 
result is [0.0, 98.73] or [27.53, 35.23]

[Screenshot case 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0hU5P2Em3ppcGRUemNtVENpWlE&authuser=0)
[Screenshot case 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0hU5P2Em3ppWWxGNHQ2RGh2UW8&authuser=0)

---

Does anyone know the reason for this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe both are global minima? What's the objective value in the two case? What are the values of `result.success`?

Comment: In both case result.success is true. 
But abs(-98 + 0*2 + 98.73) + abs(-99 + 0 + 98.73) = 1
abs(-98 + 35.23*2 + 27.53) + abs(-99 + 35.23 + 27.53) = 36.24

Comment: Why do you shoot with a Bazooka at a linear system ? Or is it just a testcase ? Code it as a Matrix. You do not need a solver,

Comment: It is a case. My function is: total_sum += abs( sum += x**2 * coef[0] + x * coef[1] + coef[2]).

Comment: Is it depends on the fact that the absolute value function is not differentiable at 0. ?

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18985884/4653428